# How to freeze properties inside a contructor function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the properties inside a constructor function immutable, i.e. the properties should not be altered either with a dot or bracket notation. E.g. I have my constructor function:

```
function OnceNamedOne() {
    Object.freeze(this.firstName = 'John');
    Object.freeze(this.lastName = 'Doe');
    this.fullName = this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}
```

I basically want to freeze the properties and hard wire their values as in the function. So, when an instance is created:

`var me = new OnceNamedOne();` and when the value I try to change the property value, it should not work - that is the following should not assign 'John' to first name: `me.firstName = 'John';`.

How could I do this?

Comment: You don't want to freeze properties, you freeze an *object*. Just call `freeze` on your whole instance after having created all properties!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't freeze a property with a primitive, but you could make it [non-writable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstname', {
  enumerable   : false,
  configurable : false,
  writable     : false,
  value        : 'John'
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tvrjs4xb/)

For multiple properties, it's probably easier to make a convenience function

```
function createNonWritable(obj, key, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
          enumerable   : false,
          configurable : false,
          writable     : false,
          value        : value
    });
}

function OnceNamedOne() {
    createNonWritable(this, 'firstname', 'John');
    createNonWritable(this, 'lastname', 'Doe');
    createNonWritable(this, 'fullname', this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tvrjs4xb/1/)

Or as noted in the comments, as the attributes has a default value of `false` you don't have to explicitly set them to that

```
function OnceNamedOne() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstname', {value : 'John'});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'lastname',  {value : 'Dow'});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullname',  {value : this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname});
}
```

Comment: reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: Thanks, how can I incorporate the above into my code. Do I have to write it separately?

Comment: For multiple properties, you can simply use `Object.defineProperties`. And since the descriptor attributes will default to `false` anyway, you'll only need to supply the `{value: …}`.

Comment: @Bergi - that's right, I always forget that they default to `false` as opposed to just attaching a property, when they would be `true` etc.